# How to inject a specific cache pool?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-cache

In my Symfony 5 application I want to use different caches for different tasks and of course for different environments.

e.g. my configuration looks like this:

```
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            cache.auth:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: app.my_custom_redis_provider
            cache.sap:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: app.my_custom_redis_provider
services:
    app.my_custom_redis_provider:
        arguments:
            - '%env(REDIS_URL)%'
            -
                retry_interval: 2
                timeout: '%env(REDIS_TIMEOUT)%'
        class: Redis
        factory:
            - Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter
            - createConnection
```

I use dependency injection with my classes. So how would I define which of those two cache pools is used by a specific class?

At the moment I get my cache like this:

```
class SapListService implements ListServiceInterface
{
    use LoggerTrait;

    private CountryServiceInterface $countryService;
    private CurrencyServiceInterface $currencyService;

    public function __construct(
        SapClientFactoryInterface $sapClient,
        CacheItemPoolInterface $cache,
        ParameterBagInterface $params
    ) {
        $sapUser = $params->get('sap_user');
        $sapPw = $params->get('sap_pw');
        $urlStruktur = $params->get('sap_struktur');
        $this->countryService = $sapClient->getCountryService($sapUser, $sapPw, $urlStruktur, $cache);
        $this->currencyService = $sapClient->getCurrencyService($sapUser, $sapPw, $urlStruktur, $cache);
    }
```

How do I configure my `SapListService` to use the cache.sap pool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained on the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#creating-custom-namespaced-pools).

> Each custom pool becomes a service whose service ID is the name of the pool (e.g. custom_thing.cache). An autowiring alias is also created for each pool using the camel case version of its name - e.g. custom_thing.cache can be injected automatically by naming the argument $customThingCache and type-hinting it with either Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface or Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface:

So in your case, you'd be able to type-hint for:

```
Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface $cacheSap
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change cache pool depending on e.g. environment, than type hinting will not help.

Bu you can change service definition with defined pool to use:

```yaml
# services.yaml
App\Service\SapListService:
    arguments:
        $cache: '@cache.auth'
```

```yaml
# services_local.yaml
App\Service\SapListService:
    arguments:
        $cache: '@cache.sap'
```